# IF Formula on Opportunity Date

Tags: formula, opportunity, if

I'm sure this is ridiculously simple. I'm trying to put Opportunities into groups based on Age

This is the formula I've written

```
IF(Opportunity_Age__c   < 100, "Short Term",
IF( OR( Opportunity_Age__c   >= 100,Opportunity_Age__c  <= 249, "Mid Term",
IF( OR( Opportunity_Age__c   >= 250,Opportunity_Age__c  <= 365, "Long Term",
IF( Opportunity_Age__c   >= 366, "365+",
NULL))))))
```

I'm getting the error below on the third line at "Long Term"

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'OR()'. Expected Boolean,
>   received Text

Can someone tell me 1, why I'm getting this error message, and 2, is there a better method?

I thought CASE might work better but I'm not sure if you can use that for ranges

Comment: you should perhaps do the OR as IF( Opportunity_Age__c   >= 250 && Opportunity_Age__c  <= 365, "Long Term")   ?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to deal with AND or OR, because the first matching condition will stop the IF-ELSE chain from continuing.

```
IF(Opportunity_Age__c < 100, "Short Term",
  IF(Opportunity_Age__c < 250, "Mid Term",
    IF(Opportunity_Age__c < 366, "Long Term", "365+")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in the formula, you are not closing `OR`, whereas I think you should be using `AND` instead of `OR`

This is how your formula should look like

```
IF(Opportunity_Age__c   < 100, "Short Term",
    IF(AND(Opportunity_Age__c >= 100,Opportunity_Age__c  <= 249), "Mid Term",
        IF(AND(Opportunity_Age__c >= 250,Opportunity_Age__c  <= 365), "Long Term",
            IF(Opportunity_Age__c >= 366, "365+",
                NULL
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From above formula, the requirement is :

- age < 100 => 'Short Term'
- (100 - 249) => 'Mid Term'
- (250 - 365) =>'Long Term'
- age >= 366 => '365+'

The formula return type is 'Text' and code is as below:

```
IF(Opportunity_Age__c   < 100, "Short Term",
IF(AND(Opportunity_Age__c >= 100, Opportunity_Age__c <= 249),"Mid Term",
IF(AND(Opportunity_Age__c >= 250, Opportunity_Age__c <= 365),"Long Term","365+")))
```